# Sort data ranges with pandas.cut

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, binning

I try to understand how to create a table of data I have divided into bins using `pandas.cut` where the data ranges are in the right order.
Using the following code to generate random ages:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ages = np.random.standard_normal(1000)*20+30
ages[ages<0]=0
ages[ages>120]=120
```

I bin the data using this line:

```
ages = pd.Series(ages, dtype=int)
ages_cut = pd.cut(ages,[0,20,40,60,80,100,120])
```

However, when I use `ages_cut.value_counts()` I get a table with the age ranges in a wrong order:

```
(20, 40]      379
(0, 20]       268
(40, 60]      233
(60, 80]       56
(80, 100]       3
(100, 120]      0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: value_counts sorts by the count by default. Try `value_counts(sort=False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of the comment of @QuangHoang, you can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with a `bins` parameter:

> **bins : *int*, optional**
>
> Rather than count values, group them into half-open bins, a convenience for pd.cut, only works with numeric data.

```
>>> ages.value_counts(bins=[0,20,40,60,80,100,120], sort=False)
(-0.001, 20.0]    334
(20.0, 40.0]      382
(40.0, 60.0]      224
(60.0, 80.0]       54
(80.0, 100.0]       6
(100.0, 120.0]      0
dtype: int64
```